# What size resistors for PD for RS485 pullup?

Tags: rs485

I have an RS485 circuit running over CAT6 cable.

I have a 120r resister between the two data lines at each end, and at one end a 680r pulldown to ground on the -ve and want to put a 680r pullup to 5v on the +ve

The problem is for a collection of reasons I don't have a 5V line at this point, I have a 12V line and ground. It would not be convenient to use 5V from elsewhere in the system and I'd really rather not wire in a voltage regulator just for a pull up.

So justification aside - what size resistors should I be looking at to solve this as a potential divide - and to help me understand, why should they be that size?

My best guess is that it should be 680r to ground and as close as I can to 952r to 12V (12 * 680 / 5) to maintain the amount of current that can flow down the 680r pullup. Is this correct? Is there anything else I am missing here?

Comment: Your 680/120/680 combination will give you 2.7V on the +ve line, just recalculate the upper one to give you the same when it's connected to 12V. I make it 2755 Ohms.

Comment: Why not draw the circuit with currents and voltages and solve with Ohm's law? Or simulate it? Your reasoning for 952 is not correct, you don't have 5V over the 680 ohms to begin with.

Comment: Ah I see your point - a separate PD is pointless as there is already a PD across the existing resistors - I just need to change the 680r pullup to a 2.7k pullup to give approximately the same voltage

Comment: @Simm not so fast. 2.7k only applies when nothing drives the bus, it will result to same voltage and current for singly terminated bus. It has different voltages with doubly terminated bus. And different currents when one of the drivers drive the bus nodes.

Comment: @Justme so given it is double terminated that would give 680/60/680 normally with 2.6V on the +ve when nothing is driving it. 

To preserve that behaviour with a pullup to 12v that would need 2655 ohms to 12V....

But that is treating it in isolation and ignoring when it is being driven. So is a 2.7k pullup to 12v instead of the 680r to 5v the right way to solve this or not???

Comment: You need to make a potential divider that produces an open circuit voltage of 5 volts with a short circuit current of 7.35 mA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the 680 ohm to 5V with something that gives the same 680 ohms impedance to same 5V open circuit. So you need a voltage divider from 12V to 5V that gives same short circuit current.

Comment: Paraphrasing: you need two resistors whose parallel combination is 680 ohms and whose ratio is 5/7. Look online for keyword Thevenin.